# Oracle Apex multiple authorizations on same page

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a requirement regarding authorizations such that if user is Admin/Editor, user can read/write page.
If user is visitor , he can read only the same page.

I created authorization scheme IS_ADMIN where exists sql query:

```
 select 1 from users where role_id in(select role_id from roles where name ='Admin')
```

Now i applied this authorization scheme on page.

In Read only, i selected function body,plsql and write:

```
If apex_authorized.is_authorized ('IS_ADMIN')
RETURN FALSE
ELSE RETURN TRUE;
END IF;
```

I applied this assuming this would make the page read only for the user which is not admin.
But because of the authorization scheme and error message that i set, i am simply getting error when i log in with visitor role. The same error message that i gave for authorized scheme.

What is the best way to apply multi authorization scheme in this case?

Apex: 20.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the authorization scheme to be `IS_ADMIN_OR_VISTOR` which would return `true` if the user was either an admin or a visitor.  That allows both admins and visitors to access the page.  Your read-only logic would then mean that visitors would see the page as read only and admins would see the page as editable.

Comment: Ok, so the authorization scheme would have all users. Then how should i write the read only logic?

Comment: If i use authorization scheme as: Roles in(Admin,User), and user the same read only logic, it is making page read only for all users

Comment: @Vini - What does `apex_authorized.is_authorized ('IS_ADMIN')` return if the user is a visitor?  I'd expect that to return `false` so that the read only statement would return `true`.  If it returns `true`, however, that would cause the page to be editable for users.

Comment: Yes you are right, but when i do this, it is makng page read only for both admin and user. The read only logic needs to be written as function code/pl sql or there is some other way to define also?

Comment: ok, i think this is a session related issue. When i log in in a new fresh session it is working. probably cache related. thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to create a security model that is based on roles and responsibilities (as done in ERP systems). A role is granted to a user (eg ADMIN, VISITOR, etc) and a responsibility is linked to application functionality (eg VIEW_EMP, EDIT_EMP). Responsibilities are then granted to roles or to other responsibilities. The authorization schemes are created on the responsibilities (the app is unaware of the roles).

Example for an EMP form: requirement is that VISITOR can see data and ADMIN can edit data

Create responsibilities: VIEW_EMP and EDIT_EMP and matching authorization schemes.
Role VISITOR has responsibility VIEW_EMP.
Responsibility EDIT_EMP has responsibility VIEW_EMP (so that whoever has EDIT_EMP automatically gets VIEW_EMP).
Role ADMIN has responsibility EDIT_EMP.

In the form you set the auth scheme of the page to VIEW_EMP and the auth scheme of CREATE/SAVE/DELETE button and DML Page process to EDIT_EMP.

So when a user with VISITOR comes to the form he gets the data but the buttons are hidden. When an ADMIN comes to the screen he sees all.